# How can I use regex to find all occurrences of 'CDS' in my file?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to look through my file to find the total number of times it says 'CDS' and I'd like to use regex for this. I'm new to python and would like to try this out.

I've tried to use re.findall(r'CDS') but it doesn't work

A sample of my file is:

```
gene            10887..10960
                     /gene="ileT"
     CDS            10887..10960
                     /gene="ileT"
                     /product="tRNA-Ile"
                     /note="codon recognized: AUC; ileT, tRNA-Ile, anticodon
                     gat, length = 74"
                     /anticodon=(pos:10921..10923,aa:Ile,seq:gat)
     gene            11112..11184
                     /gene="alaT"
     CDS            11112..11184
                     /gene="alaT"
```

So here, I'd expect 2.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong: any help would be fab!

Comment: `len(re.findall("CDS", your_text))`?

Comment: `your_file_as_string.count("CDS")`? Why regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.findall()` first argument should be the pattern you're looking for and the second be `string` you're looking into(the file).

It would be something like this:

```
occurences = re.findall('CDS', yourFile)
```

[Here is a helpful resource with some examples](https://pythonexamples.org/python-re-findall/).